# Rails config.gem error on gem installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I already have installed this gem: googlecharts.rubyforge.org, but I don't want to require it every time I need it on my actions, so I am trying to do it the Rails way:

```
config.gem 'mattetti-googlecharts'
```

Then I go and start my server and get this error:

> Missing these required gems:
>   mattetti-googlecharts
>
> You're running:   ruby 1.8.7.174 at
>   /usr/bin/ruby1.8   rubygems 1.3.5 at
>   /home/laptop/.gem/ruby/1.8,
>   /var/lib/gems/1.8
>
> Run `rake gems:install` to install the
>   missing gems.

But the gem is installed! I also tried this variant:

```
config.gem 'mattetti-googlecharts', :lib => 'gcharts'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [RubyGems repository](http://rubygems.org/gems/googlecharts). The GitHub gem is outdated.

```
$ gem install googlecharts
```

Then in your app

```
config.gem 'googlecharts'
```

You don't need to require `gchart` [because of this](http://github.com/mattetti/googlecharts/blob/master/lib/googlecharts.rb). Also note, you were trying to require `gcharts.rb`, not `gchart.rb`.

Comment: Tnxs. Can you explain why config.gem 'mattetti-googlecharts' did not work? If it were updated, should I invoke only per 'googlecharts' ?

Comment: Because you were requiring `gcharts` instead of `gchart`